# How do I move inline-javascript to script tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've got this popover which is working good, here is the html of the popover:

```
<div class="popover2"  onmouseover="$(this).mouseleave(function() {$(this).hide(); });">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="popover2-inner">
        <span class="popover2-title">Popover() 2</span>
    <div class="popover2-content">
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li><span>$200 Bronze</span><p>2 hrs. drivers training</p </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I've got this instantiation code:

```
    $('.popover2-test').popover({
    placement:'bottom',
    template: $('.popover2'),
    trigger: 'manual',
    animate: false,
    html: true,

        }).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault() ;
        }).mouseenter(function(e) {
            $(this).popover('show');
    });
```

But I want to move the inline onmouseover javascript stuff into the instantiation code. I don't know how to do this. Any help is great, thanks.

Comment: Give the tag an id and then just bind the event in JS. Unless that is the only tag with that class, in which case you can simply use the class.

Comment: Your going to have to be more specific, I don't know what your talking  about, sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried placing this line of code just after the instantiation code?

```
$('.popover2').mouseleave(function() { $(this).hide(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

just remove the inline and add:

```
$('.popover2').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no point only binding the mouseleave event onmouseover, since a mouseover event must fire before mouseleave anyway (AFAIK). So this would do:

```
$('.popover2').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

This assumes, of course, that `.popover2` exists when your 'instantiation code' runs.

If not,

```
$('.popover2').live('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```